# How to avoid creating unneeded object in an elegant way?

Tags: c#

The root of my question is that the C# compiler is too smart. It detects a path via which an object could be undefined, so demands that I fill it. In the code, I look at the tables in a DataSet to see if there is one that I want. If not, I create a new one. I know that dtOut will always be assigned a value, but the the compiler is not happy unless it's assigned a value when declared. This is inelegant.

How do I rewrite this in a more elegant way?

```
             System.Data.DataTable dtOut = new System.Data.DataTable();
            .
            .
            // find table with tablename = grp
            // if none, create new table
            bool bTableFound = false;
            foreach (System.Data.DataTable d1 in dsOut.Tables)
            {
                string d1_name = d1.TableName;
                if (d1_name.Equals(grp))
                {
                    dtOut = d1;
                    bTableFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!bTableFound) dtOut = RptTable(grp);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. (I was interested in the general problem. The code given was an example, but not of any particular importance.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That initial value can be `null`.  The compiler doesn't require you to *create an instance*; it just requires you to assign a value.

```
System.Data.DataTable dtOut = null;  // compiler is now happy
// rest of code as before
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest and most elegant way, and what I would have done.

Comment: This is probably the best answer at my level of programming complexity, but still seems inelegant to me. Fussy, fussy.

Answer (score 10):

You can rewrite your method like so:

```
System.Data.DataTable dtOut = dsOut
                                   .Tables
                                   .Cast<System.Data.DataTable>()
                                   .FirstOrDefault(t => t.TableName.Equals(grp)) 
                                 ?? RptTable(grp);
```

Comment: This uses features I'm not familiar with: a learning opportunity.

Comment: @SeaDrive: This is based on LINQ (for the cast + FirstOrDefault), and the null coalescing operator (??) to handle the null check.  It replaces your entire method.

Answer (score 1):

```
            ...program...
            {
               System.Data.DataTable dtOut = GetDataTableByName(grp, dsOut);
            }

            public DataTable GetDataTableByName(string grp, object dsOut)
            {
              foreach (System.Data.DataTable d1 in dsOut.Tables)
                {                    
                   if (d1.TableName.Equals(grp))
                     return RptTable(grp)
                }
              return null;
            }
```

If I've interperated your naming correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dtOut = dsOut != null && dsOut.Tables != null && dsOut.Tables[grp] != null 
            ? dsOut.Tables[grp]
            : RptTable(grp);
```

HTH

Comment: Why the -1 without any comment? Perhaps SO should enforce comments for down votes so that we can learn what went wrong...

Comment: Fair point, Sunny.  My guess is that the question is for C#, but your answer isn't.

Comment: This is interesting, though I'm not sure I would call it elegant. I do not find expressions using the ? operator especially easy to read. I had not thought of doing "dsOut.Tables[grp] != null" would save doing the loop which is a good answer, but not to the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

I like Otávio's answer, but here's an alternate approach anyway.  You can shove the foreach loop down into its own method, something like:

```
static System.Data.DataTable
getDataTable ( System.Data.DataTable[] tables, String grp )
{
    foreach (System.Data.DataTable d1 in tables)
        {
            string d1_name = d1.TableName;
            if (d1_name.Equals(grp))
            {
                return d1;
            }
        }
    return null;
}
```

This lets you simplify your original method to:

```
System.Data.DataTable dtOut = getDataTable(dsOut.Tables, grp);
if (!dtOut) dtOut = RptTable(grp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want elegance, go LINQ:

```
var dtOut = 
  dsOut.Tables.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TableName == grp)
  ?? RptTable(grp);
```